# How do you make a socket connection and transfer data between Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8?

Tags: sockets, windows-8, tcp, windows-phone-8

I want to send some data to my computer (i.e. `1`). When I press a button on my Windows Phone 8 and recieve data on my phone. How do you make this simple program? I already made a server on the computer and the phone but is this the data that will pass through the WiFi TCP/IP socket? ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sockets for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202874%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) would be a good start.  Since you're on Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8, use the [Windows.Networking.Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.networking.sockets.aspx) Windows Runtime API.

There are a number of [sample apps](http://dev.windowsphone.com) as well though many are from the Windows Phone 7.5 vintage and use the older [System.Net.Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.net.sockets%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Take a look though at [Tim Laverty's sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Windows-Phone-8-Networking-835239c1) from his Build 2012 presentation: [Windows Phone 8, Networking: Building Connected Apps](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-047). It contains a Socket Listener and Client for Windows Phone, but since its using the WinRT API is should be straightforward to use in Windows 8 as well.